# Search for file names containing (0-9) in windows

Tags: windows-search

How do I search and delete duplicate **files** and **folders** containing `(1)` or `(2)` in their names?

like:

```
folder(1), folder(2), file(1).exe, file(2).jpg ...
```

I need to delete such **files** and **folders**. Please advise.

Comment: You can use `for /R` with `del` or `rd` command to find and delete simultaneously.

Comment: All the solutions provided below work only for files and not for folders.

Comment: name:(~"*(?)") searches for folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all file names containing `(1).` or `(2).` you can search for:

```
name:(~"*(1).*") OR name:(~"*(2).*")
```

Also, (from comments) you can more simply match a single character between parenthesis with:

```
name:(~"*(?).*")
```

This will work in your case if you are sure that you only have numbers between the `()`.

Comment: Search for `name:(~"*(?).*")` to get any single digit result, so all results are multiple copies.

Comment: wow! Stephen Rauch, you are Amazing! I couldnt find this stuff even on google...how did you learn this man.

Comment: Oops,spoke too soon... that only worked for files and not for folders...

Comment: Worked after I changed the search to name:(~"*(?)")

Answer (score 2):

What about using a batch file to find all files with `(x)` and build a revisable Kill-List from the results?

- The following batch will exactly do this
- the search starts in the folder defined with the variable `Base`
- the results are stored in a file on the desktop including a random number.
- the results file is opened with notepad.exe to remove possible errants.
- finally you are asked if you want to execute the deletes.

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal

Set "Base=%USERPROFILE%"
Set "Report=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Kill-List_%Random%.cmd"

( For /f "delims=" %%F in (
   'dir /B/S "%Base%\*(?).*"^|findstr "([0-9])\.[^\.]*$" '
  ) Do Echo Del "%%F"
) > "%Report%"
Start "" Notepad.exe "%Report%"
Set "DoDel="
Set /P "DoDel=Do you want to execute the revised Kill-List ? [y/n]: "
If /i "%DoDel%" Equ "y" "%Report%"
```

Sample results file:

```
Del "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\UserScanProfiles\SCANPROFILE (2).XML"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\settings (2).ini"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent\mytest.csv (2).LNK"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\Neu (2).lnk"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Programm_Links\VLC media player (2).lnk"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Bilder\Screenshots\2016-09-15 (1).png"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Bilder\Screenshots\2016-09-15 (2).png"
Del "C:\Users\UserName\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot (1).png"
```

Comment: Would this work for folders?